# Oracle mod_plsql does not implement PUT and DELETE HTTP requests

Tags: oracle, http-request, http-delete, http-put, mod-plsql

I am running Oracle-Application-Server-10g and using mod_plsql for webserver. While webserver accepts HTTP requests such as POST, DELETE and HEAD, I can not find a way in setting it to accept other HTTP requests such as PUT and DELETE.
Sending **PUT** or **DELETE** request to the servers returns **"501 Method Not Implemented"**.
I have created the following part in  httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "D:\OraHome_2\Apache\Apache\htdocs">
AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS PROPFIND>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS PROPFIND>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

but it made no difference.
Can anyone propose a solution?

Comment: Don't you need `mod_oradav` for WebDAV requests? I can't find OAS 10g docs, but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e10144/under_mods.htm#i1015163) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out [node_plsql](https://github.com/doberkofler/node_plsql), my NodeJS based alternative to mod_plsql. It's currently in a very early development stage but would allow you full control over the request methods.